# How to analyze this data showing atomospheric CO2, CH4 and tempertures obtain from an ice sample?

Tags: atmosphere, climate-change, atmospheric-chemistry, co2

Here is the chart:
[image: Chart]

My questions are:

- Is the atmosphere in equilibrium over this record?
- how would I determine what the maximum and minimum values for each
  record is (approximation).
- Is there a correlation between records for CO2, CH4 and temperature?
- Are today's values within the normal range of variability for this record?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have the original data or are you digitizing?

Comment: @arkaia I suppose digitizing. All I have is the graph.

Comment: If you digitize, then you have the answer to questions 2 and 3

Comment: @arkaia what do you mean by digitize?

Comment: @arkaia I want to know if the atmosphere in this chart is in equilibrium, such as is it periodic, like at natural equilibrium to a fixed position, or is in not in equilibrium because maybe there a forcing at play and if so what is it?

Comment: @arkaia what I am trying to understand is how do you know it is out of equilibrium from the above graph?

Comment: @arkaia also I know that todays value is at depth 0 in the chart, so how might I compare the two, are today's values within the normal range of variability for this record?

Comment: @arkaia can you tell me if this is correct for the max's and min's? CO2 : MAX:280, MIN:200.....CH4: MAX: 700, MIN: <400. Did I make a mistake there?

Comment: Those might be approximate values, but you can digitize the figure and then you will know the min/max, the correlation and the trend. Without that, you are just eyeballing it

Comment: @arkaia for what I am doing it is okay to eye-ball it. I just want to make sure I am eye-balling it correctly.

Comment: @arkaia does the rest of the information I stated seem correct to you?

Comment: calculating the trend to see if it is stationary from the figure could lead to huge errors!